# Google Sheets: Parsing JSON results

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

Preface: I'm a complete novice at JS and have tried googling my solution for hours.

I am making an API call to a public endpoint using Google Sheets (within the script editor). Here's my current code:

```
function getMaterials() {
    var myUrl = "https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account/materials?access_token=[my_access_token]";
    var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
    var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();
    return jsonString;
}
```

Here's a snippet of what is returned:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12134,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 14
  },
  {
    "id": 12238,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12147,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 12142,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 12135,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12246,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Here's the documentation to the particular API I'm interacting with:

https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/account/materials

There's no real way to filter off my call, or I'd be more than happy to use that.

I am looking to query on the "id" value, but return only the "count" value in the same query. I've tried multiple ways from various sites, but can't get anywhere. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding some other JS code that did what I needed.

It allows me to feed the API through a function that formats the data into columns. I can have this data in other sheet and feed it into my main sheet.

https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the API docs for that endpoint but I guess you could transform your data to an object that uses id as keys. Depending on your use it might be better to query the API for only specific keys (ie if you only need a small amount of data) if that's possible as this would reduce the amount of data received and memory use. But failing that this should hopefully help!

```js
var data = getMaterials(); 

// Map each object by ID
function getMaterialIdMap(data){
  var materials = {}; 
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    var material = data[i]; 
    if(material.hasOwnProperty('id')){ // Ensure we only get objects with ids
      materials[material.id] = material;
    }
  } 
  return materials
}

// Map just the count to id
function getIdToCountMap(data){
  var materials = {}; 
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    var material = data[i]; 
    if(material.hasOwnProperty('id') && material.hasOwnProperty('count')){ // Ensure we only get objects with counts and ids
      materials[material.id] = material.count; 
    }
  } 
  return materials
}

// For the full object by id
var materialMap = getMaterialIdMap(data);

// For just the counts 
var materialCountMap = getIdToCountMap(data);

// For use in the sheet =countFromId(12134)   //14
function countFromId (id){
   return materialCountMap[id];
}

function getMaterials(){
  // Just a dummy data function for live snippet replace me with your version that performs the actual request and returns data as an array of objects.
   return [
  {
    "id": 12134,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 14
  },
  {
    "id": 12238,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12147,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 12142,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 12135,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12246,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 1
  }
]

}var data = getMaterials(); 

// Map each object by ID
function getMaterialIdMap(data){
  var materials = {}; 
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    var material = data[i]; 
    if(material.hasOwnProperty('id')){ // Ensure we only get objects with ids
      materials[material.id] = material;
    }
  } 
  return materials
}

// Map just the count to id
function getIdToCountMap(data){
  var materials = {}; 
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    var material = data[i]; 
    if(material.hasOwnProperty('id') && material.hasOwnProperty('count')){ // Ensure we only get objects with counts and ids
      materials[material.id] = material.count; 
    }
  } 
  return materials
}


var materialMap = getMaterialIdMap(data);


// For just the counts 
var materialCountMap = getIdToCountMap(data);

// For the full object by id
function countFromId (id){
   return materialCountMap[id];
}

function getMaterials(){
  // Just a dummy data function for live snippet
   return [
  {
    "id": 12134,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 14
  },
  {
    "id": 12238,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12147,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 12142,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 12135,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12246,
    "category": 5,
    "count": 1
  }
]

}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've added the particular API and documentation in my original post. I will try what you suggested here in a bit.

Comment: You're very welcome @jmct. Thanks for adding that :). I've had a look and I don't think that particular API endpoint allows specifying an ID so prob just have to grab them all then filter. If you have any trouble let me know and I'll have another look!

Comment: Well, I had plugged in the above code in Google Sheets' script editor, but am confused on how I should actually make the call with the ID now. Also, after adding it, I can no longer get data returned from my getMaterials function. Seeing: "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined."

Comment: I've updated the example  -the request will have to be made without and ID then we iterate over the data assigning each item to an object with its key being the ID. If `getMaterials` is returning nothing or something other than an array of objects my code would throw an error like that. Is your `getMaterials` function working fine on it's own, be sure to delete my dummy function when in use too as that may cause issues. If `getMaterials` is working you should be able to  simply `=countFromId(12134)`. I also removed a few `console.log`s as google sheets doesn't seem to define a console object.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the dummy data and the code does run clean, but the output of something like =countFromId(12134) returns nothing.

Here's the complete code (I've added the key in the pastebin for help on debugging - I can generate another later and there's no sensitive data exposed):

http://pastebin.com/unnBzARk

Comment: Looks like the request is returning a 400 status with invalid key (maybe you've since invalidated that key though). I think the more generic solution you've found is probably better anyway :)

Comment: Sorry. Yep - I did go ahead and invalidate it. Thanks for all of your help though!